# How could the Death Star still be operational in The Rise of Skywalker?

Tags: star-wars, death-star, the-rise-of-skywalker

In *The Rise Of Skywalker*, we see a door opens **automatically** in front of Rey in order to get into the room where Emperor Palpatine presumably hid the wayfinder. Any idea how that door mechanism is still operational and what is powering it even after 31 in-universe years since the station was destroyed in *Return of The Jedi*?

Comment: it's ridiculous that such a large chunk survived the blast seen at the Return OF The Jedi in the first place...

Comment: is it possible the Force-wielder in the room could have something to do w/ it?

Comment: @A.bakker the death star was the size of a small moon, several hundred kilometers across. That "large chunk" should've stretched from horizon to horizon many times over!

Comment: @BMF the explosion, created by a planet destroying laser core, engulfed the entire station

Comment: The door mechanism was made of plot armor.

Comment: @A.bakker The Visual Dictionary also hand waves this _"That any of it survived, or that the moon itself survived such a colossal impact, is a miracle in a star system filled with the unexplained."_

Answer (score 17):

It apparently had its own separated power and (genetic?) recognition system.

> Rey crept along the shadowy walls, where she hoped the floor was better supported, and came to a door. It had a complicated access mechanism that marked it as valuable and significant. Maybe a vault. What she sought was assuredly inside.
>
> She could get through this lock eventually. The Death Star had been dormant here for decades. She probably just needed to muscle it—
>
> Rey lifted a hand as if to push, but before she made contact, something clicked and the door whooshed open. **As if it still had a power source. Like she’d been recognized.**
>
> <sub><sup>[Rise of Skywalker: Expanded Edition](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Rise_of_Skywalker:_Expanded_Edition)</sup></sub>

Comment: So this answers why it opened, does it implies that its power source is The Force emanating from Rey?

Comment: @user10191234 - It seems far more likely to me that the fancy lock simply had its own power source.

Answer (score -1):

> Any idea how that door mechanism is still operational and what is powering it even after 31 in-universe years since the station was destroyed in Return of The Jedi?

This scene is like the scene in the Empire Strikes Back where Luke fights Vader in the cave on Dagobah.  As we know that Rey didn't actually fight herself just like Luke did not actually fight Vader in the cave, the door opening/closing on it's own is most likely part of her vision/hallucination.  In reality the door may have been open the whole time.

Comment: This is plausible but seems to be speculation only. Is there any evidence to support this interpretation?